# Make a cut-off timer in PHP

Tags: php

I made an online exam for 2 colleagues. Their students have an hour to complete it. Normally they will finish it much faster.

When they are finished, they click the button 'Send my answers' and PHP collects their answers and writes them to a textfile on my webpage.

I have a javascript to disable the send button, but that works on the local machine time, which can be altered.

So I would like to put something like this at the top of the php file that collects the answers:

```
<?php
// cut off time. The server is 8 hours behind Chinese time
// the exam ends 2pm
$d = new DateTime('2020-06-12 06:00');
// the time now
$time = date('Y-F-d G:i');
// check if it is too late
if($time > $d) {
        echo 'You are too late!';
        include 'jsclock.html';
        exit();
    }
?>
```

But this does not work. I must be using the wrong time format or something.

I am trying this on my localhost. The time right now here in China is 2020-06-12 11:06, so I was hoping I would get the "You are too late" message.

Any tips please?

Comment: compare two dates with the same tz with either unixtimestamps or datetime classes

Comment: OK, got it, it worked! I got my message and was sent to the jsclock.html!